# Can MYSQL tabulate results by the search values used within an 'IN' statement?

Tags: mysql

Consider the below MYSQL select query:

```
SELECT  software,
        count(*) 
FROM allmydata 
WHERE software IN  ('Version 1','Version 2','Version 3')
GROUP BY software;
```

With the above query, MYSQL will only show the software and count for matches within the database. If there are no results for value 'Version 3' in software, it won't appear in the output table.

Is there a way to have the counts for each search value in a table, even if the count is zero?

Ideal output would be:

```
+-----------+-------+
| Software  | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| Version 1 |     5 |
| Version 2 |     3 |
| Version 3 |     0 |
+-----------+-------+
```

My real-world application is slightly more complicated than this but the example above was the simplest way I could explain what I need and I figured an answer will really help me towards reaching my goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select
  x.s,
  count(*) as cnt
from (
  select 'Version 1' as s
  union all select 'Version 2'
  union all select 'Version 3'
) x
left join allmydata a on a.software = x.s
group by x.s
```

Comment: Thank you this is really useful. Is there anyway the same thing could be done where the list of search patterns is in a variable?

Comment: @Doozer The typical solution is to assemble a Dynamic SQL query with the section between parenthesis changing according to the parameters. An alternative solution is to store all those values into a [temporary] table and then use it in the join.